# 1 Node crashed of 3 node mariadb galera cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera, crash

## Heading

**I have three nodes Galera cluster MariaDB, a node in June 4, 2016 suddenly crash, the following is log error**

**Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5**
**Server version: 5.5.39-MariaDB-wsrep-log**

> 160603 13:56:06 [Warning] WSREP: SQL statement was ineffective, THD:
>   29598800, buf: 143 QUERY: commit  => Skipping replication
>   160603 13:56:06 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ; This could be because you hit
>   a bug. It is also possible that this binary or one of the libraries it
>   was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured.
>   This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
>
> To report this bug, see http://kb.askmonty.org/en/reporting-bugs
>
> We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
>   diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,  something is
>   definitely wrong and this may fail.
>
> Server version: 5.5.39-MariaDB-wsrep-log key_buffer_size=25165824
>   read_buffer_size=131072 max_used_connections=226 max_threads=802
>   thread_count=79 It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
>   key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =
>   1784371 K  bytes of memory Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some
>   variables in the equation.
>
> Thread pointer: 0x0x7f2980201000 Attempting backtrace. You can use the
>   following information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no
>   messages after this, something went terribly wrong... stack_bottom =
>   0x7f2a5d9b2cd0 thread_stack 0x48000 160603 13:56:17 [Warning] WSREP:
>   last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT11.5678S), skipping check
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2b)[0xa95ecb]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x398)[0x6ebbc8]
>   /lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x3da300f710]
>   /usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so(_ZN6galera3FSMINS_9TrxHandle5StateENS1_10TransitionENS_10EmptyGuardENS_11EmptyActionEE8shift_toES2_+0x1f)[0x7f4127f5d21f]
>   /usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so(_ZN6galera13ReplicatorSMM13post_rollbackEPNS_9TrxHandleE+0x2e)[0x7f4127f7828e]
>   /usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so(galera_post_rollback+0x68)[0x7f4127f91d88]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x6925d5] /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x6926e8]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z17ha_rollback_transP3THDb+0xe6)[0x6ee8a6]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15ha_commit_transP3THDb+0x1e2)[0x6eebb2]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12trans_commitP3THD+0x45)[0x66e1b5]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x2430)[0x5a8220]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x5acf54] /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x5ad33b]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x1889)[0x5aefb9]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x11c)[0x5af73c]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x2eb)[0x660d3b]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x4c)[0x660ddc]
>   /lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x3da30079d1]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x3da2ce8b6d]
>
> Trying to get some variables. Some pointers may be invalid and cause
>   the dump to abort. Query (0x7f2a88c1f018): is an invalid pointer
>   Connection ID (thread ID): 29598800 Status: NOT_KILLED
>
> Optimizer switch:
>   index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=off
>
> The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html
>   contains information that should help you find out what is causing the
>   crash. 160603 13:56:19 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
>   160603 13:56:19 mysqld_safe WSREP: not restarting wsrep node
>   automatically 160603 13:56:19 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
>   /PMS-db/data/lyxr-db04.pid ended

```
[MYSQLD]
user=mysql
basedir=/usr
datadir=/PMS-db
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid_file=mysqld.pid
port=3306
log_error=error.log
#log_output=FILE
#relay_log=relay-bin
### INNODB OPTIONS 
innodb_buffer_pool_size=90418M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:100M:autoextend
## You may want to tune the below depending on number of cores and disk sub
innodb_read_io_threads=8
innodb_write_io_threads=8
innodb_doublewrite=1
innodb_log_file_size=1024M
innodb_log_buffer_size=96M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
#innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_io_capacity=2000
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
## avoid statistics update when doing e.g show tables
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
engine_condition_pushdown=1
default_storage_engine=innodb
#thread_handling=pool-of-threads
#thread_pool_max_threads=2000
#thread_pool_size=32
#thread_pool_oversubscribe=3
#thread_pool_stall_limit=30
#thread_pool_idle_timeout=60

# CHARACTER SET
#collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
#init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character_set_server = utf8

# REPLICATION SPECIFIC - GENERAL
#server_id must be unique across all mysql servers participating in replication.
server_id=1
#auto_increment_increment=2
#auto_increment_offset=SERVERID
# REPLICATION SPECIFIC
binlog_format=ROW
log_bin=binlog
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
#relay_log=relay-bin
expire_logs_days=30
#log_slave_updates=1
# OTHER THINGS, BUFFERS ETC
key_buffer_size = 24M
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 256K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
skip_name_resolve
memlock=0
sysdate_is_now=1
max_connections=2000
thread_cache_size=512
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
table_open_cache=1024
lower_case_table_names=0
bind-address=192.168.16.11
slow_query_log = on  
log_queries_not_using_indexes=1
long_query_time  = 1
##
## WSREP options
##

# Full path to wsrep provider library or 'none'
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so

# Provider specific configuration options
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=8192M"

# Logical cluster name. Should be the same for all nodes.
wsrep_cluster_name="xmscluster"

# Group communication system handle
#wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://

# Human-readable node name (non-unique). Hostname by default.
wsrep_node_name=lyxr-db01
# Address for incoming client connections. Autodetect by default.
wsrep_node_address=192.168.16.11

wsrep_node_incoming_address=192.168.16.11
wsrep_sst_receive_address=192.168.16.11
wsrep_sst_auth=repluser:foxhis

# How many threads will process writesets from other nodes
wsrep_slave_threads=16

# DBUG options for wsrep provider
#wsrep_dbug_option

# Generate fake primary keys for non-PK tables (required for multi-master
# and parallel applying operation)
wsrep_certify_nonPK=1

# Location of the directory with data files. Needed for non-mysqldump
# state snapshot transfers. Defaults to mysql_real_data_home.
#wsrep_data_home_dir=

# Maximum number of rows in write set
wsrep_max_ws_rows=131072

# Maximum size of write set
wsrep_max_ws_size=1073741824

# to enable debug level logging, set this to 1
wsrep_debug=0

# convert locking sessions into transactions
wsrep_convert_LOCK_to_trx=0

# how many times to retry deadlocked autocommits
wsrep_retry_autocommit=1

# change auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset automatically
wsrep_auto_increment_control=1

# replicate myisam
wsrep_replicate_myisam=1
# retry autoinc insert, which failed for duplicate key error
wsrep_drupal_282555_workaround=0

# enable "strictly synchronous" semantics for read operations
wsrep_causal_reads=0

# Command to call when node status or cluster membership changes.
# Will be passed all or some of the following options:
# --status  - new status of this node
# --uuid    - UUID of the cluster
# --primary - whether the component is primary or not ("yes"/"no")
# --members - comma-separated list of members
# --index   - index of this node in the list
#wsrep_notify_cmd=

##
## WSREP State Transfer options
##

# State Snapshot Transfer method
# ClusterControl currently DOES NOT support wsrep_sst_method=mysqldump
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup

# Address on THIS node to receive SST at. DON'T SET IT TO DONOR ADDRESS!!!
# (SST method dependent. Defaults to the first IP of the first interface)
#wsrep_sst_receive_address=

# SST authentication string. This will be used to send SST to joining nodes.
# Depends on SST method. For mysqldump method it is root:<root password>

# Desired SST donor name.
#wsrep_sst_donor=

# Protocol version to use
# wsrep_protocol_version=
[MYSQL]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#default_character_set=utf8
[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#default_character_set=utf8
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 512M
#default_character_set=utf8
[MYSQLD_SAFE]
pid_file=mysqld.pid
log_error=error.log
basedir=/usr
datadir=/PMS-db
```